# How can I remove TinyMCE tooltip?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and showing this tooltip...  How can I disable or remote this.?
[image: Check this screenshot]

Comment: Which environment are you using TinyMCE in? TinyMCE does not show any tooltips by default. You'll want to share you initialisation code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Bootstrap tooltip. I've disabled tooltip plugin and problem is solved.